# how to export an imported package

Tags: typescript

Say for `file1` I have

```
import * as Things1 from "../things1"
import * as Things2 from "../things2"

export {
    Things1,
    Things2,
}
```

and for `file2` I have

```
import * as Distributor from "../file1"
import * as Things3 from "../../things3"
```

How do I export it so it looks like

```
export {
    Things1,
    Things2,
    Things3,
}
```

in `file2`?

I don't want to use

```
export const Things1 = Distributor.Things1;
```

because there are quite a few variables beings exported in my actual file

Comment: `export * from "../file1";` in conjunction with `export { Things3 } from "../../thing3";`

Comment: @caTS if you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export everything directly like this:

```js
export * from "../file1"; // export everything from file1
export { Things3 } from "../../thing3"; // selectively export only Things3
```